# How to fix "The SSL connection could not be established" error in RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net-core, ssl-certificate, restsharp, client-certificates

I'm using RestSharp to call a Web Api with certificate. I've already set up the certificate in Azure and I've already tested the SSL connection with the server by ping commands.

Can anybody help me with the code?

The host of the web api is a windows server.

The code is following:

```
   var client = new RestClient("<myApiEndpoint>");
   var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

   X509Certificate2 cert = null;
   X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
   certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
   X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find( X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "<myKey>", false);

   if (certCollection.Count > 0)
   {
      cert = certCollection[0];
      client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { cert };
   }

   request.AddHeader("sql", "select * FROM consumers");
   IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I expect to connect to the server as a result. But the result is a error. Error message is "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure".

Comment: You tested SSL with Ping? How? Please test with Telnet on specific port. Did you maybe used wrong port for connection?

Comment: @Andreas, It was tested in Azure. My web app is running in Azure. I have a VM with certificate in Azure. Ping is the one way for test.